# Smart way to pick a random function

Tags: swift, function, random

I am trying to pick and run a random function in swift.

Currently I have implemented a switch case like this

```
  switch Int.random(in: 1...2) {
                            case 1:   functionOne()
                            case 2:   functionTwo()
                            default:  print("error")
                            }
```

if there are more options the code gets really excessive.

How can I improve the code to make it save the extra lines?
The optimum would be:

```
  [functionOne(), functionTwo()].randomElement()
```

This does not work but just runs the last element in the array.
Is there a way to put functions in an array and let them run?

Comment: Is it given that none of your functions in your pool takes different parameter types? Otherwise this mechanic won't work at all

Comment: `([functionOne, functionTwo].randomElement()!)()`

Comment: i think @matt is on a good track, i currently have no opportunity to test that but for this none of the functions must return `nil`

Comment: If you only have 2 cases, why do you need 100 random numbers? Is it because you think `random(in: 1...100)` is more random than `random(in: 1...2)`?

Comment: @matt given what OP said there might be more cases than the two shown in the example. I guess the pool contains a variable number of functions theoretically up to 100

Comment: @Nathanael Tse how often did you test this code?

Comment: yes. the functions do not return anything.
the 100 was an example. there are more functions, but I wanted to give a leaner example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the probability of the different functions to be different then your switch statement would be a good choice:

```
switch Int.random(in: 1...100) {
                        case 1...10:   functionOne() //10% of calls
                        case 11...100: functionTwo() //90% of calls 
                        default:       noFunction()
                        }
```

If you want them all to be equally as likely then Matt's approach seems cleaner:

```
let functions = [functionOne, functionTwo]
(functions.randomElement()!)()
```

Comment: great that works,
can anyone explain why we need the (!)
and the initial version did not work?
([functionOne, functionTwo].randomElement()!)()
vs.
[functionOne(), functionTwo()].randomElement()

Comment: @NathanaelTse `randomElement` returns an `Optional`, since calling it on an empty `Array` returns `nil`. That's why force unwrapping it is safe when you call it on a non-empty array. Your version didn't work because you executed the functions and just put their `Void` results in an array, while doing `[functionOne, functionTwo]...` creates an array of closures and the `()` executes the closures (functions), that's why you need the `()` _after_ the call to `randomElement`, since you only want to execute the single selected function, not all of them.